# Aggregating by Month from epoch date - neo4j cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, average, aggregate-functions

#### Goal

**I am attempting to query neo4j for an average score, aggregated by month.**

#### Background

The date attribute in my DB is set as epoch timestamp.

#### Work so far

I have the following code so far

```
MATCH(d:data) RETURN avg(d.score), date(datetime({epochMillis:d.submitted})) AS date
```

#### Problem

This will return an average score, per day (for every day that a record exists)

I would like to get average for each month, rather than days.

#### Also Tried

I had a good google and cannot seem to find an answer which does not rely on install apoch addon (which I don't have).

I found the following, but just can't understand (like most neo4j documentation) what it is actually trying to say.
https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/temporal_types.html

**Additional**

Ideally I would like to report max 12 months back from "today" and include months even if there is no records for that month (return month name and 0), not sure if this is as simple though, so any thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing is to aggregate by year and month:

```
MATCH (d:data) 
RETURN apoc.date.format(d.submitted, 'ms', 'YYYY-MM') AS month,
       avg(d.score) AS score
ORDER BY month DESC
LIMIT 12
```

Or without apoc.date.format:

```
MATCH (d:data)
WITH d, datetime({epochMillis:d.submitted}) as dt
RETURN dt.year as year, 
       dt.month as month,
       avg(d.score) AS score
ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC
LIMIT 12
```

But if you want to use the last 12 months (or any other value) with a possible zero, then best way is to create a list of previous months (using the "duration" function), and then optional match the values in the range of dates and calculate the average:

```
WITH date() AS today
UNWIND [
  i IN range(0, 11) | 
  datetime.truncate('month', today - duration({months: i}))
] AS firstDayOfMonth
OPTIONAL MATCH (A:data) 
WHERE A.submitted >= timestamp(firstDayOfMonth) AND
      A.submitted <  timestamp(firstDayOfMonth + duration({months: 1}))
RETURN apoc.date.format(timestamp(firstDayOfMonth), 'ms', 'YYYY-MM') AS month,
       coalesce(avg(A.score), 0) AS score
```

Comment: Thanks, anyway I can do this without the `apoch` extension?

Comment: ... I replaced `apoc.date.format(timestamp(firstDayOfMonth), 'ms', 'YYYY-MM') AS month` with `date(datetime({epochMillis:timestamp(firstDayOfMonth)})) AS month` and that is working well. `left()` won't trim, causes an error but I can run with this if there is no way to replicate the tidy up without apoch. Thanks again

Comment: @Simon You are welcome. Yes, of course, apoc is used just to simplify the code. I added an example without this library.